# Sybase SQLAnywhere 12 drop foreign key

Tags: sqlanywhere

```
alter table Orders drop foreign key FK_foreign;
```

> Error: -131 syntaxi

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
alter table ORDERS drop constraint constraint_name
```

(I am more familiar with ASE , not ASA)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to try:

create table tf (id int , col2 varchar(32), constraint pk_on_id primary key(id));
alter table tf drop constraint pk_on_id;